# Write to 'text' property of HTTP response using Node HTTP module

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

Is there a way in which I can write to the 'text' property of a HTTP response using the Node HTTP module?

Currently I have something like:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {

   ...

   res.writeHead(/* some stuff here */);
   res.write(/* body stuff */);
});
```

Currently my response is like:

```
response: {
  ...
  text:{},
  body: { /* some stuff */ }
}
```

What I'm wanting to know is if I can write to 'text' instead of 'body'?

```
response: {
  ...
  text: { /* some stuff */ },
  body: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the http anatomy, you have the message header and message body.

> Currently my response is like:
>
> ```
> response: {
>   ...
>   text:{},
>   body: { /* some stuff */ }
> }
> ```

Assuming that you are trying to use vanilla Node JS, what the above statement mean is that you are going to have your own structure in the data you are going to send as the http body. (don't mistake this with the "body" of your own structure)

In this context, any data can come under any part of your structure - is the answer to your question. It is completely up to you to decide/interpret the structure of the http body you are going to send to a destination.

---

I can recommend you to use a framework like [express](https://expressjs.com/) to do most of these structuring automatically.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.status(200).json({text: 'foo', body: 'bar'})
})
```

Comment: Could you please include a basic example of how you would achieve this?

Comment: @physicsboy https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework